# Facebook log-in without Facebook app approval?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am in the last stages of creating a new iOS app which uses Facebook login api. The Facebook app I created for that (in Facebook itself), is not yet approved by Facebook since they are demanding to provide them with the Apple App ID (which currently does not exist as my future app is yet to be submitted to Apple). At this point, I am able login using Facebook inside my iOS app, however, I am wondering if other people will be able to do so once my iOS app will be approved by Apple (while it's not yet approved by Facebook)...

Comment: I think you can get an App ID by creating the app in iTunes Connect, but you don't need to upload a binary for review.

Comment: you only need to approve certain additional permissions. basic login will work without approval.

Answer (score 0):

I already got my app id in the itunes connect but Facebook requires active app id which I cannot provide at the moment.

However, I got my answer, as long as the basic permissions part is approved by Facebook, the login process will work just fine. Thanks!